# general existence theorem of nonlinear parabolic PDE on a unit circle

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I wish to study existence/uniqueness of the solutions to a system (possibly coupled) of nonlinear PARABOLIC PDE arise from biology on a unit circle.

Could any one suggest me any references for studying existence uniqueness problem of parabolic (linear or nonlinear) on a unit circle? 
(I have found enough papers for the related problem given the domain as $R^n$ (bounded or unbounded)
However, I am a bit lost what to do after I change my domain to a **unit circle**, that is the space $\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

I cannot find any parabolic examples in Friedman's book for the domain as unit circle.

Appreciate any suggestions for reference.

Comment: Do you mean a circle (closed curve, $|z|=1$) or a disk (domain, $|z|<1$)?

Comment: I mean a 1-manifold, i.e. $\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. I just don't know what function spaces I shall start with, say in $\mathbb{R^n}$ case, I start with postulating $u,v\in C(\bar{\Omega})$. Now when I switch to a circle, I have no idea what to say...

Comment: You can unroll the circle, interpreting functions on $S^1$ as  $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb R$. The function spaces like $C^k$ immediately make sense then.

Comment: Do you mean I can regard the unit circle as a bounded interval on a real line? And then the only extra thing to do is to impose some period boundary conditions instead of the usual ones....are there any references in what you suggested? Also I have emphasis in the original question that I am interested in parabolic system. But reference on elliptic nonlinear odes also may help.

Comment: Yes, imposing periodic boundary conditions makes an interval into a circle. Elementary PDE textbooks such as Strauss deal with periodic BC in the context of linear diffusion equation. For nonlinear, I have not seen it in the books, but I would expect that the methods used in bounded domains will still apply.

Comment: One more thing...you mean SPACE periodic boundary conditions (to recast the original circle domain into a bounded interval on R), right?

Comment: Yes, in space. In the time variable one usually has initial conditions, not boundary.